# GCM notification is not received when App is not running

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i'v implemented GCM and it works fine except one issue.

if application works in foreground or background notification are consumed by application. However, if notification received while application is killed. Than notification only shown in top bar. But application cant find it even when user launch app.

I notice when message is recived after rebooting device, message is shown ony on message center, but its not found by application. Than, after application started, than, it start to receive messages.

Comment: what is your actual issue ?

Comment: Makes perfect sense... How should an application which is shut down, receive the message ?

Comment: i might have misunderstanding how android works, although, it diffrent than iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Than notification only shown in top bar.

You put that `Notification` there yourself. GCM does not display a `Notification` on its own.

> But application cant find it even when user launch app.

The application "found" it to display the `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare ... I think now I undertsand the issue ... but not sure I found the best solution ... see my question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479959/best-practice-to-save-incoming-notification-for-later-app-retreival