# Receiving GCM Android Notifications while App is not Running

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

I'm confused by the [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) documentation in how to receive a notification on a client device when the app I'm developing is not running. I've tried googling and reading stackoverflow on this topic, but I haven't gotten complete clarification yet.

Do I just extend [GCMBaseIntentService](http://fryerblog.com/post/30057483199/implementing-push-notifications-with-gcm) to receive notifications, add the service name to my manifest file, and then my service that extended GCMBaseIntentService will automatically handle notifications to my app, even when the app itself is not running? Is there anything else I need to do?
Thanks!

P.S. I found a thread with a similar [title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455736/gcm-notification-is-not-received-when-app-is-not-running), but it doesn't seem to be the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [doc](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) :-

> An Android application on an Android device doesn't need to be running
>   to receive messages. The system will wake up the Android application
>   via Intent broadcast when the message arrives, as long as the
>   application is set up with the proper broadcast receiver and
>   permissions.

Then what is confusion here?

Comment: I was confused about the entry point, specifically. Is it the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver then?

Comment: Yes and in that `onReceive()` they starts `GCMBaseIntentService`.

Comment: If app is force closed by user, then notification doesn't arrive. Is there a workaround for that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Force close stops the process, so this might be the reason. I am not sure about this.